# Insert dictionary item into list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list `adImageList` of dictionary items in following form:

```
[{'Image_thumb_100x75': 'https://cache.domain.com/mmo/7/295/170/227_174707044_thumb.jpg',
  'Image_hoved_400x300': 'https://cache.domain.com/mmo/7/295/170/227_174707044_hoved.jpg',
  'Image_full_800x600': 'https://cache.domain.com/mmo/7/295/170/227_174707044.jpg'},
 {'Image_thumb_100x75': 'https://cache.domain.com/mmo/7/295/170/227_1136648194_thumb.jpg',
  'Image_hoved_400x300': 'https://cache.domain.com/mmo/7/295/170/227_1136648194_hoved.jpg',
  'Image_full_800x600': 'https://cache.domain.com/mmo/7/295/170/227_1136648194.jpg'},
 {'Image_thumb_100x75': 'https://cache.domain.com/mmo/7/295/170/227_400613427_thumb.jpg',
  'Image_hoved_400x300': 'https://cache.domain.com/mmo/7/295/170/227_400613427_hoved.jpg',
  'Image_full_800x600': 'https://cache.domain.com/mmo/7/295/170/227_400613427.jpg'}]
```

I have iterator which suppose to add local URL under each image record after fetching it from web (fetching part works ok). So I'm using following code to append local URL to existing dictionary items:

```
 for i, d in enumerate(adImageList):
                file_name_thumb = '0{}_{}_{}'.format(i, page_title,'_thumb_100x75.jpg')
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(d['Image_thumb_100x75'], file_name_thumb)
                local_path_thumb = dir_path+file_name_thumb
                adImageList.insert[i](1,{'Image_thumb_100x75_local_path_thumb':local_path_thumb}) # not working

                file_name_hoved = '0{}_{}_{}'.format(i, page_title,'_hoved_400x300.jpg')
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(d['Image_hoved_400x300'], file_name_hoved)
                local_path_hoved = dir_path+file_name_hoved
                adImageList.insert[i](3,{'Image_hoved_400x300_local_path_hoved':local_path_hoved}) # not working

                file_name_full = '0{}_{}_{}'.format(i, page_title,'_full_800x600.jpg')
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(d['Image_full_800x600'], file_name_full)
                local_path_full = dir_path+file_name_full
                adImageList.insert[i](5,{'Image_full_800x600_local_path_full':local_path_full}) # not working
```

Idea is to extend dict items in following manner **which also explains numbers 1,3 and 5 in my code**

```
{'Image_thumb_100x75': 'https://cache.domain.com/mmo/7/295/170/227_174707044_thumb.jpg',
  'Image_thumb_100x75_local_path_thumb':local_path_thumb #1,
  'Image_hoved_400x300': 'https://cache.domain.com/mmo/7/295/170/227_174707044_hoved.jpg',
  'Image_hoved_400x300_local_path_hoved':local_path_hoved #3
  'Image_full_800x600': 'https://cache.domain.com/mmo/7/295/170/227_174707044.jpg',
  'Image_full_800x600_local_path_full':local_path_full #5}
```

But it's giving me error:

> TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with `adImageList.insert[i]`? `adImageList.insert` is a method. You cannot index it.

Comment: I need to extend dictionary in each list item element as I described it.

Comment: Is `adImageList` a dictionary? How is it defined?

Comment: I defined it in the beginning of my question.  It's a list of dict items.

Comment: What is the purpose of the numbers 1, 3, and 5?

Comment: 0 - remoteURL_thumb, 1 - localURL_thumb, 2 -remoteURL_hoved, 3 - localURL_hoved, 4- remoteURL_full, 5 -localURL_full

Comment: I do not see how they are used in your example. They are nowhere in the expected output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189918/discussion-between-harvey-and-dyz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely here's what you had in mind:

```
adImageList[i]['Image_thumb_100x75_local_path_thumb']=local_path_thumb
```

This adds key `'Image_thumb_100x75_local_path_thumb'` to the `i`th dictionary on the list and sets its value to `local_path_thumb`. The purpose of 1,3,5 is still unclear.

Comment: I've added explanation for 1,3,5

Comment: Python dictionaries are not ordered (at list prior to 3.6). You should not expect new keys to be at specific positions, and you cannot insert a new key at a specific position.

Comment: Got it now. This will suffice, thank you! I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

python stack traces give line numbers for a reason, but my guess is this line:

`adImageList.insert[i]`

insert is a method

Comment: Yes, that's incorrect I guess. I realize now that I'm not adding list item but adding new dict item which is inside list